# Report JavaScript code (.js file) about module root URL

Tags: javascript, module, directory, joomla

There is a JavaScript file in the Joomla module that internally uses the loading of other .js files, these files are located in the module directory.
How can I pass the path of the current module to a .js file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the path from PHP in the JS variable inside a script tag like this:

```
<?php
$module_path = JURI::base()."/modules/mod_YOUR_MODULE/";
?>
<script>
var module_path = "<?php echo $module_path; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: ...just read your profile... if you want to earn more trophies, join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and see if you can help us to resolve more questions.

Comment: `<script>
var module_path = "<?php echo JURI::base() . "/modules/mod_YOUR_MODULE/";
?>";
</script>` you can avoid declaring a single-use php variable this way.